# Do named ranges not work under certain conditions?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importhtml

Been tearing my hair out today with this one.  I'll be as concise as I can.

I have a number of named ranges, and I would like to reference them in a long, ugly formula that works without them just fine.  However things get weird when I start to switch to named ranges.

The original, working formula:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B38&TEXT(I38,"yymmdd")&H38&TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(J38,".",""),"0000000")&"0","table",1),3,2)
```

The values in use are:

```
B38: COH
I38: 09/16/16
H38: P
J38: 41.00
```

It constructs the proper URL and imports the desired table using `index()`.  All is well.  The final URL is `http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/COH160916P00041000`

But now I start adding named ranges rather than cell references and things go sideways.

This fails with an error:    `=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&Symbol&TEXT(Expires,"yymmdd")&Trade_Type&TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(Strike_Price,".",""),"0000000")&"0","table",1),3,2)`

All of the named ranges are valid and get properly color coded, but I get the error:

```
Function INDEX parameter 2 value is 3. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive.
```

Now to make things more interesting... I can put this in another cell:

```
="http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&Symbol&TEXT(Expires,"yymmdd")&Trade_Type&TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(Strike_Price,".",""),"0000000")&"0"
```

And it constructs a perfectly proper URL that works fine.  I can then reference that cell from my original formula like so:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML(AB37,"table",1),3,2)
```

and it all works perfectly.

So what on earth is going on here?  Why won't my named ranges work directly in the initial `index(importhtml())` formula?

Comment: In order to be able to reproduce the problem, add the values of the reference or add a link to a demo spreadsheet having only the formulas and the named ranges and the corresponding values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding why INDEX does not work when there are named ranges as parameters, but does work in the other cases, it is not clear to me yet.

I was thinking that the problem is that [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) requires that its first parameter be a reference to a spreadsheet range, as it's stated in the official documentation.

Besides the formula forms that you already found, you could try to use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=es) instead of INDEX. Example:

```
=QUERY(
  IMPORTHTML(
    "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&
      Symbol&
      TEXT(Expires,"yymmdd")&
      Trade_Type&
      TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(Strike_Price,".",""),"0000000")&
      "0",
    "table",
    1
  ),
  "select Col2 where Col1='Bid'",
  0
)
```

`Bid` is the label for the third row, so I used it to get the value at row 3, column 2.

There are other alternatives but they will depend on the use case an your personal preferences as a spreadsheet user.

Comment: Ah very interesting, I didn't know about `query()` so thanks for that!  So my `index()` version will work when the first parameters is a sheet reference, even if that sheet reference is the result of `importhtml()`, but it won't handle a named range directly.  Very interesting... thanks for the explanation!  Oh and it works great in my application btw.  =)

Comment: Now that I read your comment, I think that I should think again about my response :)

Comment: @JonathanvanClute: Is you found helpful my answer, please remember to upvote it.

Comment: Oops, thanks I always forget to do that!

Comment: I stand corrected, your solution works perfectly in some places, and not at all in others.  I don't understand.  This formula - `=query(IMPORTHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&Symbol&TEXT(Expires,"yymmdd")&Trade_Type&text(substitute(Strike_Price,".",""),"0000000")&"0","table",1),"select Col2 where Col1='Bid'",
  0)` works on some cells and not others, when filled down.  When it fails, the error is `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2`.  How can this be when the column definitely exists??

Comment: Oh and this is with or without using named ranges.

Comment: Please post your follow-up question as a new question and include the relavant details like how many query(import) formulas have your spreadsheet and what are the values of the named-ranges.

Comment: OK I'll post a separate question and include a copy of the sheet.